# CSS: increase the space or width of &nbsp visually?

Tags: css, whitespace

Can we increase the space or width of `&nbsp;` when we see it on a browser?

For instance,

```
Home &nbsp; Away
```

I would like it to have a **bigger space between** these two words instead of adding too many `&nbsp;`

Or maybe there are other solutions rather than using `&nbsp;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommed to go for CSS instead

```
<span>Home</span><span>Away</span>

span
{
padding-left:5em; //use padding or margin according to your need 
margin-left:5em;
}
```

Otherwise you can go for `<pre>` tag which parse white spaces in HTML docs

Answer (score 9):

A better solution, without using extra markup, using CSS `word-spacing`:

```
<p>Home Away</p>
```

And the CSS:

```
p{ 
    word-spacing:30px;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Rmp9/1/)

This will allow you to effectively separate *design* from *content* in your code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `&emsp;` instead:

```
Home &emsp; Away
```

Answer (score 2):

Click here to view [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Rmp9/)

### Html

```
 <div>  Home  <span class="spacing">Away</span>

 <div>
```

### Css

```
.spacing {
    margin-left:10px; //just set the required spacing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already plenty of good answers.

Just to make the posibilities list greater, you can set

```
span {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

and then just set as many spaces as you want

```
<span>Home Away</span>
<span>Home   Away</span>
<span>Home    Away</span>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sx278/)